# extracting polygon from googlemaps URL

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can I read the polygon from a search result like this:

https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Joliette,+QC/@46.0108031,-73.4916076,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cc8bdb99340567b:0xc6448884fc5822a6!8m2!3d46.014012!4d-73.4177961

Should I use a layer in my map? Or use the map.Data ?
I know there is a google: libraries=places but I cannot see how to use it.

Is Google actually forbidding us to read their precious database?
What's the use of a such a API if we cannot do such a simple thing!

I saw at least 2 posting from guys wanting to do exactly the same thing!

### Thanks in advance

Francois

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get polygons for map features via Google APIs.

Actually, there is a feature request for this in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109

However, it doesn't look like this has a priority.